# Is it possible to list a module's named ES6 exports without importing its dependencies?

Tags: javascript, module, export, ecmascript-6

I'd like to get a list of all named exports of a module, but don't want to import the module's dependency tree.

Why? I'm writing a `gulpfile` that will perform operations on a series of subfolders, whose names match the export names I'm trying to get. I'm not doing anything with the modules themselves. I'm just transpiling code, not running it; secondary dependencies may therefore not be installed and cause my build script to fail.

Here's an example.

**gulpfile.babel.js:**

`import index from 'index.js';
gulp.task('default', () => {
  Object.keys(index).forEach(exportName => 
    gulp.src(path.join(exportName, '/**'))
    // ...transpile code in each folder
  );
});`

**index.js**

`export ModuleOne from 'moduleOne';
export ModuleTwo from 'moduleTwo';`

**moduleOne/index.js**

`import thing from 'notCurrentlyInstalledPackage';`

Running `gulp` fails because I haven't `npm install`ed `notCurrentlyInstalledPackage`. It's treated here as an external dependency, to be resolved in a different bundle.

Comment: So essentially...How can check the exports of a module when you don't have access to it?

Comment: @JordanHendrix right. Whoops. Edited the question.

Comment: What will happen if a module will be imported with dependencies? It is not clear if you're referring to `import` ES6 statements or the actual Node modules that are required with `require`. The code won't hurt.

Comment: @estus Some of the secondary dependencies are not available because they're not necessarily installed. I'm referring to ES6 `import`. I'll add some code.

Comment: It is not possible for `import`, and it requires some black magic to do this with `require`. Use `require` or `System.import` to dynamically import the dependencies that may be unavailable.